# Kwicks slider with vertical headings

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to create a slider as in the following link
http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_37383/index-4.html

I have created a slider using the kwicks plugin, but have not been able to add the vertical headings

HTML

Javascript:
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.kwicks').kwicks({
            size: 125,
            maxSize: 250,
            spacing: 5,
            behavior: 'menu'
        });
        $('.kwicks').kwicks('expand', 0);
    });

CSS:
     .kwicks {
         width: 515px;
         height: 100px;
     }
     .kwicks > li {
         width: 125px;
         height: 100px;
         /* overridden by kwicks but good for when JavaScript is disabled */
         margin-left: 5px;
         float: left;
     }
     #panel-1 {
         background-color: #53b388;
     }
     #panel-2 {
         background-color: #5a69a9;
     }
     #panel-3 {
         background-color: #c26468;
     }
     #panel-4 {
         background-color: #bf7cc7;
     }

Comment: This is the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/A6XkM/

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/A6XkM/5/

note: use a webkit browser. (chrome or safari)

```
<ul class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal'>
    <li id='panel-1' data-text="Text1"></li>
    <li id='panel-2' data-text="Text2"></li>
    <li id='panel-3' data-text="Text3"></li>
    <li id='panel-4' data-text="Text4"></li>
</ul>

.kwicks > li:after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I also need it to be in a block as in the link.
Thanks alot for your help.